# Razor post form not returning object with user inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to update an object in an in memory list, as shown in the PluralSight ASP.NET Fundamentals course. I have run into a problem that when my Update methods is being called from my Edit.cshtml.cs file it is with a default instance of the MeetingSpace class I have created instead of one using the input provided by the user. I have attached the Edit.cshtml and Edit.cshtml.cs files.

[image: The edit page in browser]

[image: The list displayed after an edit is made]

If I save the submission, and return to the meeting space table, the top entry is now set to the default object (note the table initially has two rooms named "Meeting Room 1")

Changing the first (or any object) in the list using the browser results in it being replaced by an empty object. I have tested the update method independently and it works as intended and when debugging I can see an default MeetingSpace item being used as the argument in the Update method, so I believe the problem is either with the form or the retrieval of the inputs by the .cs file.

Edit.cshtml

```
@page "{meetingSpaceId:int}"
@model BookingApp.Pages.MeetingSpaces.EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Editing @Model.MeetingSpace.Name</h2>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="MeetingSpace.Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MeetingSpace.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="MeetingSpace.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MeetingSpace.Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MeetingSpace.Location"></label>
        <input asp-for="MeetingSpace.Location" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MeetingSpace.Location"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MeetingSpace.Capacity"></label>
        <input asp-for="MeetingSpace.Capacity" class="form-control" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="MeetingSpace.Capacity"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Edit.cshtml.cs

```
namespace BookingApp.Pages.MeetingSpaces
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IMeetingSpaceData meetingSpaceData;

        [BindProperty]
        public MeetingSpace MeetingSpace { get; set; }

        public EditModel(IMeetingSpaceData meetingSpaceData)
        {
            this.meetingSpaceData = meetingSpaceData;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet(int meetingSpaceId)
        {
            MeetingSpace = meetingSpaceData.GetById(meetingSpaceId);
            if (MeetingSpace == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./NotFound");
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            MeetingSpace = meetingSpaceData.Update(MeetingSpace);
            meetingSpaceData.Commit();
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs I am using an AddSingleton to update an in memory list, as such:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMeetingSpaceData, InMemoryMeetingSpaceData>();
            
            
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

I'm a fairly inexperience programmer and am completely new to ASP.NET so hopefully I have provided you with enough information.

[Edit 1]
MeetingSpace.cs (int id field provided by parent class)

```
namespace BookingApp.Core
{
    public class MeetingSpace : MeetingObjectsBaseClass, IEquatable<MeetingSpace>
    {
        //private static int classCount = 3;          //TODO: Change to 0 default when database implemented
        public string Name;
        public string Location;
        public int Capacity;

        public override void EditDetails()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Equals(MeetingSpace other)
        {
            if (Name == other.Name
                && Location == other.Location
                && Capacity == other.Capacity)
            { 
                return true; 
            }
            else 
            { 
                return false; 
            }
        }

        public override int GenerateNewId()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void GetAll()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

[Edit 2] Parent Classes

MeetingObjectBaseClase

```
namespace BookingApp.Core
{
    public abstract class MeetingObjectsBaseClass : BookingEntityBase
    {
        public abstract void GetAll();
        public override abstract void Update();

    }
}
```

MeetingEntityBase

```
namespace BookingApp.Core
{
    public abstract class BookingEntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public abstract void EditDetails();
        public abstract void GenerateNewId();

    }
}
```

[Edit 3] InMemoryMeetingSpaceData.cs

```
public class InMemoryMeetingSpaceData : IMeetingSpaceData
    {
        public List<MeetingSpace> meetingSpaces;

        public InMemoryMeetingSpaceData()
        {
            meetingSpaces = new List<MeetingSpace>()
            {
                new MeetingSpace { Id = 1, Name = "Meeting Room  1", Location = "The Building", Capacity = 8},
                new MeetingSpace { Id = 2, Name = "Meeting Room 2", Location = "The Building", Capacity = 4},
                new MeetingSpace { Id = 3, Name = "Meeting Room 3", Location = "The Building", Capacity = 6},
                new MeetingSpace { Id = 4, Name = "Meeting Room 4", Location = "The Building", Capacity = 8},
                new MeetingSpace { Id = 5, Name = "Meeting Room 1", Location = "Second Building", Capacity = 7}
            };
        }

        public MeetingSpace Add(MeetingSpace newMeetingSpace)
        {
            if (newMeetingSpace != null)
            {
                meetingSpaces.Add(newMeetingSpace);
                newMeetingSpace.Id = meetingSpaces.Max(m => m.Id) + 1;
            }
            return newMeetingSpace;
        }

        public IEnumerable<MeetingSpace> GetAll()
        {
            return from m in meetingSpaces
                   orderby m.Name
                   select m;
        }

        public MeetingSpace Update(MeetingSpace updatedMeetingSpace)
        {
            var meetingSpace = meetingSpaces.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == updatedMeetingSpace.Id);
            if (meetingSpace != null)
            {
                meetingSpace.Name = updatedMeetingSpace.Name;
                meetingSpace.Location = updatedMeetingSpace.Location;
                meetingSpace.Capacity = updatedMeetingSpace.Capacity;
            }
            return meetingSpace;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public MeetingSpace GetById(int id)
        {
            return meetingSpaces.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
        }

    }
```

Comment: My first guess is that you need to remove **MeetingSpace.** from all your asp-for attributes so **MeetingSpace.Name** becomes **Name**

Comment: @JochemVanHespen Hi, doing this results in an error CS1061: 'EditModel' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found.

Comment: ow yes is see I misread some of your code lemme check something

Comment: Can you post class definition for `MeetingSpace`?

Comment: Ignore my first comment you're doing it right :)

Comment: @JochemVanHespen I have added it to the end of the question

Comment: Does `MeetingObjectsBaseClass` contain extra properties (like Name, Location and Capacity)?

Comment: @JochemVanHespen there is only an id property from a grandparent class, I have added both parent and grandparent classes to the question

Comment: I also added the InMemoryMeetingSpaceData class which stores and manages the list

Comment: This question was answered in another post I made here https://stackoverflow.com/q/69617620/11247664.